# Menu bar duplication with visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I encountered this problem with my Visual Studio 2012 IDE
[image: Menu bar entries shown twice]
That is the menu items are repeated two times.I closed VS and reopened again, also I restarted my system, but the issue persists. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Retagged. For whatever reason, MS is fond of re-doing their MSVC UI, so this is reasonably likely a VS2012-only problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to low disk space in C drive. Once memory space was increased issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but more than enough disk space. So, I ran this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /safemode /setup` and it worked.